# Append checkbox to list item

Tags: jquery, append

I am making a List of genre's with lists of playlists inside them. Right now I can render the list and everything works, but when I try to add a checkbox to each playlist list item inside the genre's list it only shows the first genre object and only one playlist list item.

```
function render(data) {
    // Itterate through each item in the list.
    $.each(data, function(genre) {
        // Create a new genre list item.
        let listItem = $('<li/>')
            .text(genre)
            // Append it to the list in the UI.
            .appendTo(list)
        // Create a new playlist's list
        // appended to the genre's list item.
        let playlistList = $('<ul/>')
            .appendTo(listItem)
        // Itterate through each playlist's item.
        let playlists = data[genre]
        $.each(playlists, function(i) {
            // Create a new playlist list item.
            let playlistListItem = $('<li/>')
                .text(playlists[i])
                // Append the playlist to the playlist's list.
                .appendTo(playlistList)
            // Create checkbox.
            let checkbox = $('<input/>') // <-- THIS IS WHERE THE CODE BUGS.
                .type('checkbox')
                // Append to current playlist list item.
                .appendTo(playlistListItem)
        })
    })
}
```

If I remove the checkbox input element, everything works as it is supposed to. I tried to make a sample function where I just create one of each element, and in this function it bugs as soon as I have two *let* statements right after each other, so I suppose that might cause the problem somehow, but I don't know how to fix it.

**UPDATE:** [link](https://jsfiddle.net/fx9hf8wz/1/) to fiddle

Comment: can you create a fiddle example with your code+html so that we can actually test and understand your problem and rectify it?

Comment: Just updated the post with a link to fiddle. @AlivetoDie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the code to the following

```
let checkbox = $('<input>')
    .attr('type', 'checkbox')
    // Append to current playlist list item.
    .appendTo(playlistListItem)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. Is there anyway I can have the checkboxes show in front of the list items instead of behind them? @Gerard

Comment: Use .insertBefore() instead of .appendTo()

Comment: I tried this, but now they are not on the same row. If I use display: inline-block, then all the list items are displayed on the same row. Is there anyway I can line them up, so the checkbox is right before the text on each item?

Comment: @Gerard have you got any suggestion? ^

Comment: Add the following to your CSS: input { float: left; clear: left; }
input + li { float: left; list-style: none; }

Comment: Correction: .list > li, input { float: left; clear: left; }
input + li { float: left; list-style: none; }

Comment: Thank you! One last thing, can you tell me how I can avoid the list sliding up when I press a checkbox? @Gerard

Comment: You need to put a span around the text in the top list (rock, pop) and check the click on that. Now you check the click on the li which contains the input elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can also write this:

```
let checkbox = $('<input/>',{type:'checkbox'})
```

With this method you can also set other attributes very simple:

```
let checkbox = $('<input/>',{type:'checkbox',id:'myid',name:'myname'})
```